# I cannot add a product in PrestaShop v1.6.1.0

Tags: sql, database, exception, prestashop-1.6

I can't add product in back office. Prestashop 1.6.1.0 throws exception:

> Unknown column 'product_attribute_shop.id_product' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT product_shop.id_product,
       Ifnull(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute, 0)
       id_product_attribute
FROM   `ps_product_reductions` pr,
       `ps_product` p
       INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop
               ON ( product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
                    AND product_shop.id_shop = 1 )
       LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop
              ON ( p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product`
                   AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1
                   AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = 1 )
WHERE  p.id_product = pr.id_product
       AND ( pr.id_product_attribute = 0
              OR product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute =
           pr.id_product_attribute )
       AND product_shop.`active` = 1
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   `ps_category_product` cp
                         JOIN `ps_category_group` cg
                           ON ( cp.id_category = cg.id_category
                                AND cg.`id_group` = 1 )
                  WHERE  cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)
       AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ( "both", "catalog" )
ORDER  BY Rand()
LIMIT  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you taked data from Prestashop in other version, or your Prestashop did not upgrade correctly.

e.g. Changes in 1.6.1 database [are here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/install-dev/upgrade/sql/1.6.1.0.sql#L91).

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a quick fix but it helped me. Are able to access phpmyadmin? Than go to your database and find the table

product_attribute_shop .

Add a column 
id_product to it with INT(10) and not null.

Than try to access your shop after doing this. the error should go away.Hope this helps.

Also I would suggest take a back up and upgrade your Prestashop version too.

Comment: Is the problem connected with PrestaShop 1.6.1.0 only?

Comment: Add new theme, is that next error you are getting ? Have you checked the ps_theme table? Does it have the theme you are using. Like for example I use default-bootstrap. does your theme have entry in the table? Also @MagdalenaDziesińska can i ask if you have ssl turned on??

Comment: @belford I had this problem with 1.6.0.6 .So i think its not limited to the version.